# Got error "Service principal was not found" when trying to add a certificate to an azure app

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I am following the example on https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/samples/active-directory-dotnet-daemon-certificate-credential/ to authenticate a daemon app with certificate to a service app using Azure AD. I have done the following:

- create my own Active Directory
- create the daemon application in the AD
  Name: TodoListDaemonWithCertYanlin
  Sign-On URL: http ://TodoListDaemonWithCertYanlin
  App Id Url: http ://TodoListDaemonWithCertYanlin
- create a self-signed certificate 
  makecert -r -pe -n "CN=TodoListDaemonWithCertYanlin" -ss My -len 2048 TodoListDaemonWithCert.cer

When I try to add the certificate to the daemon application in PowerShell, I got an error.

The PowerShell command that I used:  New-MsolServicePrincipalCredential -AppPrincipalId  "e5dedde0-2221-4ce4-a74d-af4e96705c01" -Type asy
mmetric -Value $credValue -StartDate $cer.GetEffectiveDateString() -EndDate $cer.GetExpirationDateString() -Usage verify

The error is: *New-MsolServicePrincipalCredential : Service principal was not found.*

"Get-MsolServicePrincipal -SearchString TodoListDaemonWithCert" returned a bunch of applications, but mine is not included.

I doubt that Azure might search my org's AD instead of the AD that I created. But I have no idea how to debug the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved.

Here are why it happened: I logged into Azure using my org's credential, then created a testing Active Directory, and created the Todo List Daemon application in my testing Active Directory. When I signed into Azure in PowerShell, I used my org's credential. Seems Azure PowerShell will look for application principle in my org's AD only, not in my testing AD - there might have a way to switch AD, but I do not know yet.

Here are how I solved the problem:

- Went to https://manage.windowsazure.com and tried to sign in using a user in my testing AD.
- Azure prompted that the user was not associated with any subscription. Follow the "Sign up" link to sign up with a free trial subscription.
- Wait a couple minutes for the tenant to be provisioned
- In PowerShell, sign into azure using the user in my testing Azure AD, and run the PowerShell again. Now it succeeded.

Here are the PowerShell cmdlets that I ran:

```
connect-msolservice
$cer = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate
$cer.Import("D:\Fast1\dev\TodoListDaemonWithCert.cer")
$binCert = $cer.GetRawCertData()
$credValue = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($binCert)
New-MsolServicePrincipalCredential -AppPrincipalId  "e5dedde0-2221-4ce4-a74d-af4e96705c01" -Type asymmetric -Value $credValue -StartDate $cer.GetEffectiveDateString() -EndDate $cer.GetExpirationDateString() -Usage verify
```